# Ferramentas js, CSS entre outras

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, vue.js, gulpjs

Venho percebendo cada vez mais ferramentas como. Webpack.js, gulp.js, node.js, react.js, less, sass, jquery, angular. Muitas como funcionalidades próximas. Outras nem tanto.

Algumas podem trabalhar juntas, porém isso não deixará uma aplicação pesada? Com tanto arquivo pra ser carregado?

Como encontrar uma maneira de se trabalhar com tantas ferramentas em harmonia em um projeto só?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É importante ter em mente a utilidade de cada uma dessas ferramentas durante o desenvolvimento.

O Webpack, por exemplo, é uma ferramenta que permite a geração de um ou mais bundles de acordo com a organização dos módulos do seu aplicativo. Note que essa é uma ferramenta que somente será utilizada no desenvolvimento, ou seja, não será entregue ao cliente final, e portanto não terá influência no "peso" do build final.

O mesmo raciocínio se aplica ao SASS/LESS e o Gulp.js que são ferramentas utilizadas apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, para acelerar e tornar melhor a atividade de desenvolver uma aplicação. Por estarem apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, elas não tem influência na velocidade do carregamento quando o cliente acessar a sua aplicação.

Já o React/Angular/JQuery são bibliotecas - o angular é um framework - que permitem e facilitam a construção de uma aplicação. Ao contrário dos gerenciadores de script (Gulp), compiladores (SASS/LESS) e bundlers (Webpack), estas dependências são entregues ao cliente, e estas sim influenciam na velocidade de carregamento da página.

Algo a se ter em mente no desenvolvimento atual, é a ascensão dos SPAs, coisas em que o Angular, o React e mais recentemente o VueJS tem tido destaques. Sendo assim, utilizar em conjunto o Angular e o React, por exemplo, em uma mesma aplicação não é uma das ideias mais inteligentes e vai influenciar no carregamento de sua aplicação. Cabe a você enquanto desenvolvedor analisar as utilidades de cada biblioteca em seu projeto e julgar se elas são necessárias ou se alguma dependência pré-instalada já realiza tal ação.